# Why math processing error in chrome for Wikipedia?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using chrome. But unfortunately, i'm facing the math processing error after applying cookie clear and shift+restart/reload/refresh. Not works but work in firefox and other browsers. Also, work in guest session of chrome. Please help me out. Here is the screenshot of the error.
N. B. Is there any reason for the font in chrome?

[Math Processing Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLeTI.png)

Comment: Have you started Chrome with sudo for any reason?

Comment: No. I launched chrome with desktop icon.

Comment: I know it is off-topic, but: Have you tried Chromium? It uses with all Google/Chrome features, but IMO within Ubuntu works much better than Chrome.